# mirth connect stop message propagation through destinations

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

I am using Mirth Connect 3.5.0.8232.
I have a Database Reader as source connector and a JavaScript writer as destination connector. I decided to put some fancy code in the destination, doing four separate things, which should follow one after the other. Basically I just wrote the code and it seemed to me that it was too long and too clumsy, so I decided to split it into 4 destinations that would be daisy-chained, via the "Wait for previous destination" option.

The question is : How do I interrupt this chain of execution if an error occurs on one of the destinations?

I found a JIRA issue from 2013 saying that actually the errors that would occur in the body of the Destination Connector would not prevent the message from going to all other Destinations. And it states that the 2.X version behavior is still current, i.e. an error that would occur in the Destination Transformer, will actually stop the message from propagating.

I tried throwing errors in both the Destination body, and in Destination Response Transformer, and in both cases the message would continue to other Destinations. I also tried returning ResponseFactory.getErrorResponse from the Destination body with no luck. I also tried setting responseStatus to ERROR in Destination Response Transformer to no avail. Did they mean the normal Transformer/Filter?

Also - maybe my particular solution of splitting a task into 4 distinct destinations was NOT the reason why the destinations were created in the first place? I think that the documentation states that destinations are basically what the actual word Destination stands for.

If the above case is true, maybe there are better ways of organizing the code functionally in Mirth? I think including external JS files is not allowed in JavaScript writer - even if it were, i would prefer everything to sit inside the Channel itself and be exportable/importable as a single file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, when an error is thrown from a filter/transformer, it's considered truly "exceptional" and so message flow is stopped (subsequent destinations in the same chain are not executed).

If an error is thrown from the actual destination dispatcher or from the response transformer, that destination is marked as *ERROR*, but subsequent destinations will still be executed.

You can still stop the message flow if you want though. Use filters on your subsequent destinations:
[image: Filter]

Comment: thank you, Nick, that was what I was looking for. btw $('dX') seems to be like the response returned by the corresponding destination, where X is the Id of the destination. they are seen in the "Available Variables" list, along with other channel variables, when you are creating a filter (at first I was wondering what was that..)